# Firebase.auth returning null variable

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have this function in my html file

```
    <script>
var auth = null;
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "....",
    databaseURL: "....",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "....",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    auth = user;
});

alert(auth.displayName)
</script>
```

the problem is that the auth variable is not set, and I receive it as a null message.
trying to use the function

```
var user = firebase.auth (). currentUser;
```

I receive the same error, the variable is not set.

how can I call the user variable without having to call the function each time

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all onAuthStateChanged called when auth state changes. So if it is signed in, signed out, or when the user's ID token changed in situations such as token expiry or password change.

Right now you want to log in user. USe signInWithEmailAndPassword or ... Also you need create user from firebase page or createUserWithEmailAndPassword.

Read more about Auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth
Here you can find all methods available

Finally you can get user with firebase.auth().currentUser

Comment: I already have a registration page and login, I used this function for other pages ie if a user connects to a page and the user is logged in the function tells me the username of the user who is connected but with the firebase.auth (). currentUser function does not provide it to me.